# App force closes due to actionbar theme - android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, theming

I am using actionbarsherlock. with my custom theme

In the values/styles.xml i have entered this.

```
<style name="Mytheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>
```

**actionbar_bg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="8%" 
    android:startColor="#969696" 
    android:centerColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
    android:angle="270"
/>
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.Secondactivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
         android:theme="@style/Mytheme">
 </activity>
```

**Logcat Error**
Unable to start activity, android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class

The app works fine when I remove the **android:theme="@style/Mytheme"** Line

**UPDATE:** 
I changed android:background to just "background", and the app doesn't force close now. but the gradient is not applied. all I could see is a grey actionbar.

**UPDATE #2**

modified styles.xml as follows

```
<style name="Mytheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>
```

In Manifest I call the theme as
android:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme" .

as you can see in the image the gradient is spread across the window and not just the actionbar

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this actionbar_bg.xml

[image]

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bg);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

actionbar_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerX="8%"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#969696"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I get an error...... java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.

Comment: i don't think so. i have already tried your all code but i can't find any solution. in last i fount this code which i give you in ans. and Simple b ho sakta he. just create gradient image. :)!

Answer (score 1):

Try without `android` in your xml attribute name:

```
<style name="Mytheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>
```

The one with `android` would be for native ActionBar.

Comment: oops! the app doesn't force close now, but the gradient is not applied all I see is a full greyish actionbar.

Comment: <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>.......
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>  ......I added these two lines and the gradient appears but not in the actionbar but as the background of my app. how do I solve this..

Comment: But it is still not on actionbar but on whole window?

Comment: Read code in my post carefully (in actionbar style you should remove second attribute, and add it in Mytheme style). And this is important: in Manifest you should call the theme as `android:theme="@style/Mytheme"` not `MyActionBarTheme`. And read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html :)

Comment: second attribute?. check this image, I am calling Mytheme in manifest now. http://i.imgur.com/oNXHxHK.png

Comment: Looks like I forgot to inherit from Widget :o

Comment: I don't think we would be needing widgets inheritance, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/jr9mv-5FKKI this link has the answer but i have tried this with no sucess.

Comment: Yes you do, from this link: `second step, adjust your styles.xml file in values folder and add following line to your ActionBar style`. ActionBar style is this second one which inherits from Widget.